# Does Swagger UI overshadow the login endpoint?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, swagger, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm using OpenAPI 3.0 (or Swagger UI) to document and also test the REST endpoints of my Spring Boot project. After integrating Spring Security with JWT-based authentication and authorization, I can call all non-authenticated endpoints from Swagger UI except for `login/`. Since I can call `login/` with curl

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8080/api/v1.0/auth/login' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "mail": "norman.eugene@macdonald.com",
  "password": "string"
}'
```

I suppose Swagger does somehow overshadow the login endpoind and Swagger UI gets stuck when I call login (see below).

[image: Endpoint for logging in is called from Swagger UI. Request is loading indefinitely.]

What is the problem here? Should I just rename the login endpoint? I need to login to get the JWT token in order to continue working on and testing my service.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Thank you, Helen! The browser console said `Error: Required parameter req is not provided`. In the controller, I used the annotation `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter`, replacing it with `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody` helped!